# Are you allowed to work hol hamoed if you enjoy your job?

Tags: halacha, melacha-creative-work, employment, chol-hamoed

If you're bored and do freelance. If this freelance is a hobby as well (art, programming, web design, etc), can this sort of work be done during hol hamoed?